# Try to install driver of Wireless adapter RTL8188CE

Tags: wireless

I'm very new at linux at all and my first challenge is to make enable my wifi adapter RTL8188CE on Ubuntu 16.04

What I did:

1. download driver from [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true)
2. extract the package, then command `make install`
3. got the following error:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/build M=/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o
In file included from /home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:39:0:
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/pci.h:247:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl_pci_probe’
 int __devinit rtl_pci_probe(struct pci_dev *pdev,
               ^
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:318:12: error: assignment to expression with array type
  hw->flags = IEEE80211_HW_SIGNAL_DBM |
            ^
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:331:13: error: assignment to expression with array type
   hw->flags |= IEEE80211_HW_SUPPORTS_PS |
             ^
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:365:4: error: ‘struct ieee80211_hw’ has no member named ‘channel_change_time’
  hw->channel_change_time = 100;
    ^
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_action_proc’:
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:885:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
       rx_status.freq = hw->conf.channel->center_freq;
                                ^
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:886:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
       rx_status.band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                                ^
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_beacon_statistic’:
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:1160:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘compare_ether_addr’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (compare_ether_addr(hdr->addr3, rtlpriv->mac80211.bssid))
      ^
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_send_smps_action’:
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:1451:24: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
   info->band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                        ^
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_store_debug_level’:
/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:1684:8: error: implicit declaration of function ‘strict_strtoul’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  ret = strict_strtoul(buf, 0, &val);
        ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o] Error 1
Makefile:1402: recipe for target '_module_/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ivan/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic'
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have no idea what to do with that?

Comment: Why do you want to compile those drivers from source? If you need support for your device, that's build into Ubuntu's stock kernel but may require some firmware from the `linux-firmware` package.

Comment: Let's start by identifying your device. Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: Please [edit] your post, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: result of command:  `1:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01) Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8195] Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce`

Comment: finally solve my problem.  did it with the command: `sudo modprobe -r $(lsmod | grep ^rtl | awk '{print $1}' | xargs)`  <don't now is it correct, but it's working